# Inference time changes for YOLO with different interval time between requests

Tags: pytorch, yolo, yolov5

I have the following simple script that runs the yolov5s model for image inference. However, if I insert an `time.sleep(2)` in the for loop, the average inference time will increase a lot. What could be the problem?

```
import os
import torch
from PIL import Image
import time

ROOT_PATH = os.environ.get("ROOT_PATH", "..")
MODEL_SOURCE = ROOT_PATH + "/dependencies/yolov5"
MODEL_PATH = ROOT_PATH + "/models//yolo/yolov5s"
DEVICE = torch.device('cuda:0')

def load_model():
    model = torch.hub.load(MODEL_SOURCE, 'custom', path=MODEL_PATH, source='local')
    model.to(DEVICE)
    return model

def main():
    model = load_model()
    avg_time = 0
    count = 20
    
    for _ in range(count):
        image = Image.open(ROOT_PATH + "/images/kitchen.webp")
        t1 = time.time()
        results = model(image)
        t2 = time.time()
        avg_time += t2 - t1
        print(f"Time elapsed: {t2 - t1}")
        # this makes difference
        # time.sleep(2)

    print("Average time: ", avg_time / count)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
# with time.sleep(2), the inferecne time pattern is always like this, start with 9th loop, the inference time will increase a lot.
Time elapsed: 0.054245710372924805
Time elapsed: 0.024655580520629883
Time elapsed: 0.017188310623168945
Time elapsed: 0.0163266658782959
Time elapsed: 0.01728343963623047
Time elapsed: 0.014595270156860352
Time elapsed: 0.016335487365722656
Time elapsed: 0.015712738037109375
Time elapsed: 0.03265953063964844
Time elapsed: 0.02926349639892578
Time elapsed: 0.03238844871520996
Time elapsed: 0.031163930892944336
Time elapsed: 0.028283119201660156
Time elapsed: 0.03512239456176758
Time elapsed: 0.028989076614379883
Time elapsed: 0.027245521545410156
Time elapsed: 0.01793360710144043
Time elapsed: 0.024689197540283203
Time elapsed: 0.016361713409423828
Time elapsed: 0.026474952697753906
Average time:  0.0253459095954895
```

```
# without sleep
Time elapsed: 0.05458378791809082
Time elapsed: 0.025354385375976562
Time elapsed: 0.017561674118041992
Time elapsed: 0.016532421112060547
Time elapsed: 0.01777052879333496
Time elapsed: 0.01485443115234375
Time elapsed: 0.016752958297729492
Time elapsed: 0.016268014907836914
Time elapsed: 0.019514083862304688
Time elapsed: 0.017979145050048828
Time elapsed: 0.019189119338989258
Time elapsed: 0.018964529037475586
Time elapsed: 0.016851186752319336
Time elapsed: 0.022213220596313477
Time elapsed: 0.017797231674194336
Time elapsed: 0.016551494598388672
Time elapsed: 0.01830887794494629
Time elapsed: 0.01486515998840332
Time elapsed: 0.016211271286010742
Time elapsed: 0.01635599136352539
Average time:  0.01972397565841675
```

I tried add `torch.cuda.synchronize()` before the t1 stamp, but results are the same.